# Get vscode to find the definition for dynamically imported Javascript module?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, module, dynamic-import

Is there any way to tell vscode how to find definitions from a dynamically imported module? (The module is in my source code tree.)

Comment: what about it isn't working for you? It works fine for me. Ex. in a.js: `export const a = 1; export const b = 2; export const c = 3;`, and then in b.js: `(async () => { const a = await import("./a"); })();` the type of a is `typeof import("/.../a")`, and I get suggestions for the various exports of the `a` module. Try my example and see if it works for you. And if you're having a specific problem, provide a [mre].

Answer (score -1):

follow these steps:

1. open your VS code settings select -> "Preferences: Open User Settings"
2. Settings -> search for "javascript.preferences.importModuleSpecifier".
3. Click "Edit in settings.json"
4. In the "javascript.preferences.importModuleSpecifier" section, add

```
"javascript.preferences.importModuleSpecifier": {
  "myModule/*": "${workspaceFolder}/path/to/myModule/*"
}
```